# Add a single JSON body POST REST request in an otherwise NestJS GraphQL project

Tags: node.js, nestjs

To start off, I'm a NestJS noob. There is no clear guide that I can find to understanding this, so I'm starting here. I have a NestJS GraphQL project that I'm working on, and I want to add a POST JSON body request to it, where and how should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a controller class using the `@Controller()` decorator from `@nestjs/common`. Second, add a method to the class that is decorated with the `@Post()` decorator, also from `@nestjs/common`. Third, add this class to the `controllers` array of an `@Module()` that is imported by the root module. Add route prefixes to the `@Controller()` and `@Post()` as required. That's it. Nest will set up the `GET /graphql` and `POST /graphql` routes via the `GraphQlMoudle` and will create the `POST /whatever/route/you/chose` based on the controller you just created upon startup